# RDS boto How to use database DEFAULT value

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm using AWS API gateway and boto3.client to execute SQL statements.

I am tring to insert a row where I'd like the resulting query to be the database DEFAULT:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (name, ...) VALUES (DEFAULT, ...);
```

where the column has been defined as:

```
`name` varchar(191) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'db-default-name'
```

At run-time I sometimes have a string value for `name`, in which case I define the parameter like so:

```
{'name': name, {'value': {'stringValue': 'run-time-name'}}
```

But sometimes not and in those cases I'd like the DB default value to be inserted.

I have tried this to set the parameter definition:

```
{'name': name, {'value': {'isNull': True}}
```

but then I get an error that the column cannot be NULL, which is correct, but doesn't help.

If I specify None in my python code like so:

```
{'name': name, {'value': {'stringValue': None}}}
```

I get an error too about the None value, that it is not a string value ...

Is there now way around this?

Comment: Have you tried omitting name entirely (delete the key from the dict)?

Comment: Hi, yes, then I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`. Also tried to include the variable name, but then pass an empty dictionary where otherwise the `stringValue` etc. would be. Same error.

Comment: Add your code that's producing exceptions to your post